# Using Windows 8 Store App Share Contract

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

As I understand the share contract for Windows 8, when I provide some information in a share contract, I should see any installed apps that are capable of consuming that information.  I have the following code:

```
request.Data.SetText(myString);
```

However, when I select Share, I'm presented with only the mail app.  What I'm after is a way to launch a work processor (e.g. MS Word) from my app.  Is there something else that I need to do to mark the data I'm sharing as "compatible" with Word?  Or is this just not possible because Word is a desktop app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the share contract to move data from a Windows Store app to a desktop app.  If you look at Sharing and Exchanging Data - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464923.aspx - it states, "One advantage the clipboard has over sharing is that it's the **only way to move data** from Windows Store apps to the desktop, and vice versa."

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you can't share data to desktop apps, also the target app needs to register itself as a share target for sharing to work.

You mentioned though that you wanted to launch Word. This is possible using the [Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx) class if you have a Word file that you need to open:

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Test.doc");
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

Comment: Yes, but ideally I'd like to be able to pass some text over, so I'd have to create the word document in the first place.

Comment: @pm_2 Unfortunately I don't know of any existing library which would allow you to do that, like [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) does for desktop apps. Doing it by hand is possible but not easy. Maybe you could try including an empty file with the app as a template and then programmaticaly modify it to include your text. A docx file is just a bunch of zipped XML files after all.